# Why wasn't curl able to connect to bit.ly?

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl

I was trying to install Hyperledger Fabric and the sample code and examples they have, following the instructions [on their page](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). However, when I tried to execute the following command:

`curl -sSL https://bit.ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s`

I was getting the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

After doing some minor debugging, I saw that the issue was that it was trying to find a cert file with the name `909be051.0` in `/etc/ssl/certs/`. After doing a quick search I saw that the name of the file is a specific hash, based on an openssl naming convention. I tried to make sense of the suggestion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36143311/6459998), but I did not have this `rootcert.pem` it mentions.

Then I tried uninstalling and re-installing curl. That did not work. I tried to update the certificates by running `update-ca-certificates` and also tried to rehash by calling `c_rehash`. Those did not work.

Then I found this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755968). I looked up this command (e.g. [here](https://kimconnect.com/linux-how-to-display-the-ssl-certificate-of-a-remote-server-url/)) and also read about it [here](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html), and used it to try and get the SSL certificate for bit.ly, like this:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername bit.ly -connect bit.ly:443 > cacert.pem`

Then I copied the certificate to the certificates directory `/etc/ssl/certs`, did an `update-ca-certificates` and `c_rehash`, and retried the curl command, but again it didn't work. I must say I called `c_rehash` without specifying any directories, and my `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable is empty, so maybe I didn't do the procedure right. At any rate, I then used this certificate directly in the `curl` command, like this:

`curl -vsSL https://bit.ly/2ysbOFE --cacert ./cacert.pem | bash -s`

and got

```
...

* Connection #0 to host bit.ly left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh'
*   Trying 185.199.109.133:443...
* Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (185.199.109.133) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: ./cacert-bitly.pem

...

* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 1
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

which shows that the certificate I provided seemingly worked for the connection to `bit.ly`, but now curl is trying to connect to `raw.githubusercontent.com`, using the same `.pem` file I provided, which does not contain the certificate for that second domain. So then I reused the previous command to get the certificate for `raw.githubusercontent.com`, namely:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername raw.githubusercontent.com -connect raw.githubusercontent.com:443 > cacert-githubusercontent.pem`

Again I copied this second certificate to the certificates directory `/etc/ssl/certs`, did an `update-ca-certificates` and `c_rehash`, and retried the curl command, but again it didn't work (again, I may have done the updating the wrong way).
Then I appended the second certificate to the first, so that both will be available in one file for the curl command, like this:

`cat cacert-githubusercontent.pem >> cacert.pem`

Finally, I run:

`curl -vsSL https://bit.ly/2ysbOFE --cacert ./cacert.pem | bash -s`

and it worked.

My questions are:

- why was the certificate for bit.ly missing?
- what is the reason curl could not figure out on its own which certificate to use?
- why was curl asking for the file `909be051.0`?
- was the way I did it safe, security-wise?
- could I have done it more easily?

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: I was doing all that on a Ubuntu 18.04.6 running in a VMWare VM.

Comment: You may have got man-in-the-middled and shown a falsified certificate